# Create lines of string where the number of lines is equal to the number of elements in a list

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create a function where it takes the length of a list and can produce lines of string where the number of lines is equal to the number of elements in said list.

For example, `if for list x, len(x) = 2`, and I want to produce:

```py
Hello
Hello
```

Or if `len(x) = 3`

```py
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

How could I code this for any length, which is bigger than 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print("Hello\n" * len(x))`

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop that iterates over each item in the list, and in the loop body, print your desired message.

```
for x in mylist:
    print("Hello")
```

Comment: Thanks! Easy question I know!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in multiple ways:

1) As @jordanm said in a comment, you can do it in such a way (when you multiply a string by integer Python returns a new string that is repeated the given (`len(x)`) number of times):

```
def my_func():
    print("Hello\n" * len(x))
```

2) As @John Gordon said in the answer you can do it like this (iterate over your x list, print will be called exactly len(x) times):

```
def my_func():
    for _ in x:
        print("Hello")
```

3) Or you can do it this way (iterate over `range(len(x))` iterable which contains numbers from 0 to len(x) - 1 (both ends included) - print function will be called exactly len(x) times):

```
def my_func():
    for _ in range(len(x)):
        print("Hello")
```

In all these examples `x` is your list

Answer (score 1):

First, we have some list (input data). You said that you need a function, so we'll then define it. Then the ('[for](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)') loop executes when position *i* is included in the list (in our example: 3 places (note that Python starts counting at 0)). This happens 4 times (0, 1, 2, 3). Then we just execute the function and we are done. Also look at the comments, which explain everything.

```py
# Define our list:
exampleList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Define our function:
def function():
    for i in exampleList:
        print('Hello')

# Execute our function:
function()
# --------------------------------------
# Result:
# Hello
# Hello
# Hello
# Hello
```

You can also do this with the [while](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) loop.

```py
exampleList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def function():
    i = 0
    while i < len(exampleList):
        print('Hello')
        i += 1
function()
```

*Just don't stop asking the questions and don't forget to add 'i += 1' at the end of the while loop ...*